# JavaScript ++ operator not working correctly

Tags: javascript, arithmetic-expressions

Why is it that when I run the JavaScript code below, it alerts 10?  I would expect it to alert 11.  I tried this in multiple browsers.

```js
var t=5;
t+=t++;
alert(t);
```

Comment: You are using post increment

Comment: Why would you expect 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rewrite it a couple times to expand out each step, assuming `t = 5`

```
t += t++;
// same as
t = t + t++;
// same as
t = 5 + t++;
// same as
t = 5 + (t = t + 1, 5); // the second 5 here is the old `t` value
// same as
t = 5 + 5; // the `t = t + 1` becomes obsoleted by the other `t =`
// same as
t = 10;
```

So what have we learnt? Write it longhand,

```
t = t + t + 1;
// or
t = 2 * t + 1;
// or if you really like +=
t += t + 1;
```

---

If you're wondering why `t++` is the same as `(t = t + 1, 5)`, it is because of how `foo++` is defined, it means

1. Remember the value of *foo*, lets call this *old_foo*
2. Increment *foo* by `1`
3. Return *old_foo*

If we were to write it as a function, pseudocode

```
function (foo) { // passing foo by reference
    var old_foo = foo;
    foo = foo + 1; // imaging this is a reference set
    return old_foo;
}
```

Or, using the [**comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator),

```
foo = foo + 1, old_foo;
// i.e. if `foo` was `5`
foo = foo + 1, 5;
```

Comment: I think the fact that `t = 5 + t++` becomes `5 = 5 + (t=t+1, 5)` instead of `t = 5 + (t=t+1,t)` needs a bit more explication.

Comment: @MarkReed does the stuff under the line help out?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you used `t++` instead of `++t`
The first one evaluates the number first then increments, whereas the second does the opposite.

```
t = 5; t += ++t // => 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to assume that given `left += right`, `right` is evaluated *first* and then added to `left`. However, that is not the case.

From the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> **12.14.4 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation**
>
> AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. ...

As you can see, the left side is evaluated before the right side, i.e. `t` is evaluated before `t++`, and at that point `t` is still `5`.